# create contain file log coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I want create a log file. I tried but its show me an error. Can anyone help? I show my full code here:

http://pastebin.com/SxAMCUnv

Please see this line. I don't know what happened with it, can output error:

```
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('API.log')#" 
    output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No"
```

---

**Edit:** I tried and it showed me an error:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 213 at column 110. ColdFusion
>   was looking at the following text:
>
> ''
>
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> ```
> A cffile tag beginning on line 213, column 2.
> ```

The main error is in this line:

```
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('Info.log')#" 
   output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No"
```

Please tell me what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

A superficial glance at your code suggests you're trying to write out a variable `fileContent`, but at no point do you actually set that variable. Without seeing the error, there;s no way of knowing if that's the problem, or the variable is being created in code that you *haven't* included.

Another consideration is that you're re-inventing the wheel slightly here. ColdFusion has an inbuilt [`<cflog>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d0d.html) tag or [`writeLog()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS48D04B65-0694-44e9-9E35-F9D7C9152B6C.html) statement for writing to log files.

=====

UPDATE (based on updates to the question)
That's a compile error you're getting, and the line that's erroring is not the line you indicated in your code (@ pastebin), which is a bit odd. Can you confirm line 213 is that `<cffile>` line? And can you reproduce that line in its entirety (the snippet you quoted was incomplete). But basically the error message is telling you what's wrong: you have a syntax error in your code. It could be in the specific statement the error message says (line and column), although sometimes depending on the code, the CF compiler can get confused and a syntax error in a preceding line might be reported as being further down the file than it actually is. But for starters, post the whole line of code, not just the first bit of it.

Comment: Be that as it may, you're not new to asking questions, are you? Turn it around... if someone was asking *you* the question... think about what info you'd need to be able to answer them. We need the same sort of info.

Answer (score 1):

***comments tl;dr version -***
This answer worked but asker began asking questions about the new error, he was urged to create a new question.

***Answer:***
I don't see this line in the link you posted (I searched for `api.log`).  `Invalid CFML construct` typically means you have a syntax error, usually forgetting a closing quote, second pound, or closing your tag (greater than).  If the below suggestion doesn't work, look above or below the line containing the cffile for a missing part of a closing pair.

The code you posted:

```
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('API.log')#" output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No"
```

...does not have a closing greater than to close your tag. If that is your actual code, I would suspect that is the problem.

```
<cffile ...  >
            ^^^ this is missing right here
```

If you're not going to take Adam's suggestion and use cflog (which you should), you also probably want `action="append"` or you will keep overwriting the file with the contents of fileContent.

**==edit==**

On a side note, this will not solve your problem but you should be using cfqueryparam, especially when using user entered data.

For example:

```
Select * 
FROM   Purchasers 
WHERE  PurchaserID = #PurchaserID#
```

Should be

```
Select * 
FROM   Purchasers 
WHERE  PurchaserID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PurchaserID#">
```

Comment: thank you to Travis. I am trying fix now. You can see  in there with full code : http://pastebin.com/BEMgLVTw

Comment: I see the last cffile does not have a > but it writes to info.txt and not api.log per your original post. did you change it, omit some code, or looking at the wrong file?

Comment: if it is the last line of code the error matches the description because '' (empty string) is what CF would be looking at instead of the > to close the tag.

Comment: i tried to fix as you said. but when i try to run, if show me error: We're sorry, but our system encountered an error. Please go back try again.
(If you need to reference this error the logged error ID is: e19-63619)

We monitor the error logs and work to fix the logged errors regularly.

Comment: so now it sounds like you have fixed the CF construct problem and you have a new issue to troubleshoot.

Comment: No Travis that is full code. I try add > to close tag. but when i try run my app it show me error:  We're sorry, but our system encountered an error. Please go back try again. (If you need to reference this error the logged error ID is: e19-63619) We monitor the error logs and work to fix the logged errors regularly.

Comment: but when i remove that line, my app is good. now can you help me, how do i can create a file to log data from users

Comment: does the logged error ID is: e19-63619 say Invalid CFML construct found on line 213 at column 110. ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

''  or something else?

Comment: yes only when i remove line: <cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('API.log')#" output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No">. My app run very well.

Comment: no when my web show : Invalid CFML construct found on line 213 at column 110. I fixed, i added a > to close tag. it dont show that error agian, now trying test my web, now show me :We're sorry, but our system encountered an error. Please go back try again.
(If you need to reference this error the logged error ID is: e19-63619)

We monitor the error logs and work to fix the logged errors regularly.

Comment: right... so I fixed the problem in your original post.  You will have to look at the error log your website keeps to see the actual error.

Comment: i tried create new account, and login agian, but it show that error too, Travis. can you give me email, i can show you a picture to see error.

Comment: now is show: Mailto: [empty string] Message: Variable FILECONTENT is undefined. QueryString: ordertype=Corporate&SessionID=68111134&ProgramID=23995&cfid=15882059&cftoken=18799938 RemoteAddress: ......................................vv.vv

Comment: that would probably be correct. filecontent should contain the stuff you want to put in the file but you never tell it what it is.

Comment: i think i make error in .filecontent. I dont know how do can log all data from users, ex: name,address,phone,email. May you see my code in here: pastebin.com/BEMgLVTw and fix for me ?

Comment: This is a different question but probably something like `<cfset fileContent = "#billingFristName# #billingLastName# #...what ever else you want to record...#">`

Comment: now do i have to add a line use ' <cfset fileContent = ' before this line ' <cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('API.log')#" output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No"> ' ??????

Comment: yes, you must tell CF what is in fileContent before it can be used. you will also want to use `action='append' not 'write'` and you should also just look into cflog like Adam suggested, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: can you share me your email?

Comment: doing so would exclude anyone else who wants to help from the conversation so that would be a bad idea.  you should accept this answer as the original question has been answered and ask another question about your new problem.

Comment: sorry @Travis, now i am trying check my problem.

Comment: now i am trying to use <cflog file="info.log" application="no" text="#BillingAddressOne# #BillingAddressTwo# #BillingCity# #BillingState# #BillingZipCode# #BillingCountry# #BillingPhone# #BillingEmail# #pmtmethod# #CardType# #form['Credit Card Number']# #expmonth# #expyear# #CCverificationCode# #CreditCardName#"> . but not run. i try input but nothing in info.log

Comment: create a new question please so others can help.