# please help me with cflog in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create contain file log coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946934/create-contain-file-log-coldfusion)

i want create file to log filecontent. i trial but it show me error.

this error

`Invalid CFML construct found on line 213 at column 110. ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

''

The CFML compiler was processing:

A cffile tag beginning on line 213, column 2.`

my file code in here http://pastebin.com/BEMgLVTw?
Main erorr in this line

`<cffile action="WRITE" file="#expandpath('Info.log')#" output="#filecontent#" addnewline="Yes" fixnewline="No"`

please tell me to know, what happening? thanks you
thank you everyone

Comment: Agreed: same as the other question (which is already being addressed, albeit slowly). Voting to close.

Comment: Admin Cameron. Please help me